# Appending a div in angular material upon button click with content from a input using ng-bind

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-material

I am using a input form and I want to append a flexbox containing the data from that input. Whenever the user enters the note in the input and clicks the button, a flexbox-item needs to be appended in the flexbox-container containing the text from that input. The flexbox does get appended upon the click but with no text. In the buttoncontroller function, you can see I am trying to append the flexbox div but the "usernote" is simply not displayed. What am I doing wrong?

HTML-

```
   <md-content layout-padding>
        <form name="projectForm" class="inputForm">
           <div class="inputContainer" ng-cloak>
           <md-input-container class="md-block">
              <label>Add a note</label>
              <input required class="usernote" ng-model="usernote">
              </md-input-container>
              <md-input-container>
              <label>Add Description</label>
              <input required class="userdescription" ng-model="userdescription">
              </md-input-container>
              <md-checkbox ng-model="data.cb1" aria-label="Category1">
        Category1
      </md-checkbox>
      <md-checkbox ng-model="data.cb1" aria-label="Category2">
        Category2
      </md-checkbox>
    <div class="buttondemo" ng-controller="buttonController">
<md-button ng-click="addnoteflex()" class="md-fab" aria-label="add">
              <md-icon class="material-icons">add</md-icon>
           </md-button>               
  </div>
     </div></form>
```

JS-

```
angular
        .module('firstApplication', ['ngMaterial'])
        .controller('buttonController', buttonController)
        .controller('sideNavController',sideNavController)
        .controller('speedDialController', speedDialController);
     function sideNavController ($scope, $mdSidenav) {
         $scope.openLeftMenu = function() {
           $mdSidenav('left').toggle();
         };
     }  
   function buttonController ($scope) {
        $scope.title1 = 'Button';
        $scope.title4 = 'Warn';
        $scope.isDisabled = true;
        $scope.googleUrl = 'http://google.com';
        $scope.addnoteflex=function()
        {
        var myflexbox = angular.element(document.querySelector( '.flex-container' ));

        myflexbox.append("<div  ng-bind='usernote' class=\"flex-item\"  layout=\"row\" layout-margin> </div>");
        }
     }  
     function speedDialController ($scope) {
        this.topDirections = ['left', 'up'];
        this.bottomDirections = ['down', 'right'];
        this.isOpen = false;
        this.availableModes = ['md-fling', 'md-scale'];
        this.selectedMode = 'md-scale';
        this.availableDirections = ['up', 'down', 'left', 'right'];
        this.selectedDirection = 'down';
     }
```

Answer (score 1):

There are two ways to solve the issue. One, Update your append code to this:

```
myflexbox.append("<div class=\"flex-item\"  layout=\"row\" layout-margin>"+ 
                 $scope.usernote + "</div>");
```

So, you'll have current scope var value & create html string using it. 
Working plunker link: https://plnkr.co/edit/Sj0rxDReVxSWU7zhDJWz?p=preview

Other solution is you've to compile the string which contains angular expressions  using $compile so your function's code might look:

```
$scope.addnoteflex=function(){
    var myflexbox = angular.element(document.querySelector( '.flex-container' ));
    var myhtml = "<div ng-bind='usernote' class=\"flex-item\"  layout=\"row\" layout-margin> </div>";
    var content = $compile(myhtml)($scope);
    $timeout(function(){
      myflexbox.append(content);
    });
};
```

But I guess you don't want this. Because of course this append string with ng-bind, will behave as a dynamic data block with its value updating continuously as you change value of input so it'll not be constant. If you want it to work like above solution, create dynamic variable each time you click addbutton & then use it to bind the data to div.

Instead what you can do is in add button you just push usernote value to soe notes array & on load just append that html string with ng-repeat on that notes array instead of ng-bind on usernote:

```
var myhtml = "<div ng-repeat='note in notesArray track by $index' 
         class=\"flex-item\"  layout=\"row\" layout-margin> {{note}} </div>";
var content = $compile(myhtml)($scope);
$timeout(function(){
  myflexbox.append(content); 
});
```

Here's working plunker example: https://plnkr.co/edit/extO5UI0RgMPYXJsylny?p=preview